# FASTAPI SQLAlchemy PSQL How to Post data with relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic, fastapiusers

```
migrations
src
src/__pycache__
src/auth
src/auth/__pycache__
src/auth/base_config.py
src/auth/manager.py > incapsulated funcs like create
src/auth/models.py > user
src/auth/schemas.py > pydantic classes for handling requests
src/auth/utils.py
src/place
src/place/__pycache__
src/place/manager.py > incapsulated funcs like create
src/place/models.py > place, placeimage, review
src/place/schemas.py > pydantic classes for handling requests
src/__init__.py
src/config.py
src/database.py > db conn
src/main.py > routes
.env
.env.example
.gitignore
alembic.ini
README.md
requirements.txt
```

Hello! First I show my code and ask then.

src/auth/models

```py
metadata = MetaData()
Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class User(SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable[int], Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email: str = Column(String(length=320), unique=True, index=True, nullable=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False)
    hashed_password: str = Column(String(length=1024), nullable=True)
    registered_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
    is_active: bool = Column(Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
    is_superuser: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    is_verified: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
```

src/place/models

```py
metadata = MetaData()
Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

def _resolve_user_model():
    from auth.models import User

    return User

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title: str = Column(String(length=320), unique=True, nullable=False)
    about: str = Column(String(length=320), nullable=False)

class Place(Base):
    __tablename__ = "place"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title: str = Column(String(length=320), unique=True, nullable=False)
    latitude: float = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    longitude: float = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(_resolve_user_model().id), nullable=False)
    reviews = relationship("Review", back_populates="place")
    images = relationship("PlaceImage", back_populates="place")


class PlaceImage(Base):
    __tablename__ = "place_image"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    photo_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    photo_url = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_verified_photo: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    place_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("place.id"), nullable=False)
    place = relationship("Place", back_populates="images")

class Review(Base):
    __tablename__ = "review"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String, nullable=False)
    place_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("place.id"), nullable=False)
    place = relationship("Place", back_populates="reviews")
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(_resolve_user_model().id), nullable=False)
    user = relationship(_resolve_user_model())
```

Problem is 1. Can't create POST request in @app.post(/create-place) to create place which will contain list of place images **AND** user (creator) ID (I use FASTAPI_USERS lib).

```py
class PlaceImageCreate(BaseModel):
    photo_name: str
    photo_url: str


class PlaceCreate(BaseModel):
    title: str
    latitude: float
    longitude: float
    user_id: int
    images: List[PlaceImageCreate]

class TestCreate(BaseModel):
    title: str
    about: str
```

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from src.place.models import Place, PlaceImage, Test
from src.place.schemas import PlaceCreate, TestCreate
from fastapi import Depends
from auth.models import User
from auth.base_config import current_user

async def create_place(db: AsyncSession, place: PlaceCreate, current_user: User = Depends(current_user)) -> Place:
    db_place = Place(
        title=place.title,
        latitude=place.latitude,
        longitude=place.longitude,
        user_id=place.user_id
    )
    db.add(db_place)
    await db.commit()
    await db.refresh(db_place)
    return db_place
```

I tried this block of code and it works ofc

```py
async def _create_test(db: AsyncSession, test: TestCreate) -> Test:
    db_test = Test(
        title=test.title,
        about=test.about
    )
    db.add(db_test)
    await db.commit()
    await db.refresh(db_test)
    return db_test
```

but I dont understand how to make places with images, userid and reviews...

Comment: When submitting a Place, are you including a list of images under the `images` entry? It would then be the responsibility of your controller / endpoint to iterate over `place.images` and create the expected image entries in the backend. The request is a representation of what the browser is sending, how you want to process and use that is all up to you (for example, iterating over the list and fetching each image from the db to confirm that it is valid and belongs to that user).